# TypeError: <function context_today at 0xaaa7064> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to return date to the date field when i change my division

Here is my Python code

```
        tea_worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.worker').search(cr, uid, [('bpl_division_id', '=', division_id), ('default_work', '=', 'tea')])
        for record in self.pool.get('bpl.worker').browse(cr, uid, tea_worker_ids):
            tea_list_data.append({'worker_id': record.id, 'worker_emp_no': record.emp_no, 'is_selected':True,'date': (fields.date.context_today)})#
        tea_v['selected_tea_workers'] = tea_list_data
```

this is the error

```
2013-05-13 06:22:28,810 15393 ERROR ABC werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 159, in run_wsgi
    execute(app)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/werkzeug/serving.py", line 146, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/simplejson/__init__.py", line 286, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/simplejson/encoder.py", line 226, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/simplejson/encoder.py", line 296, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/simplejson/encoder.py", line 202, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <function context_today at 0xaaa7064> is not JSON serializable
```

please help me to sort this issue,

**EDITED**

when it changed to `fields.date.context_today()`
then error comes as below

```
  File "/home/bellvantage/Documents/openerp-7.0/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl.py", line 1059, in on_change_division
    workers_list.append({'worker_id': record.id,'start_date': fields.date.context_today()})
TypeError: context_today() takes at least 3 arguments (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its worked with

```
workers_list.append({'worker_id': record.id, 'start_date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'selected':True})
```

Comment: Thanks Priyan..! this time its really working. thank you again for the answer.

Comment: This is a broken solution because lacking i18n support.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `context_today` is a method, not a value. You need to call it:

```
tea_list_data.append({'worker_id': record.id, 'worker_emp_no': record.emp_no,
                      'is_selected':True,'date': (fields.date.context_today())})
```

Comment: thanks Dear Daniel.but now another error occured & says less arguments given.please help to sort this issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here fields.date.context_today is a method, so you need to pass argument, so it will be look like,

```
tea_list_data.append({'worker_id': record.id, 'worker_emp_no': record.emp_no,
                                  'is_selected':True,
                                  'date': (fields.date.context_today(self,cr,uid,context=context))})
```